# Is it possible to replace DOM elements with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to render a `<section>` element using React but only if certain conditions are met.

The problem is I can't nest the `<section>` within a `<div>` so the highest level DOM element besides `<body>` is `<section>`

My HTML:

```
<section id="my_element"></section>
```

My React:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="container">
    ...
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('my_element')
);
```

I know with Angular directives you can replace the original DOM element with your rendered element by using `replace: true`

```
app.directive('myElement', function(){
  return {
    replace: true,
    ...
    }
  };
});
```

Is something similar available in React?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686796/react-render-replace-container-instead-of-inserting-into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently implemented yet:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1311

Follow this issue to see development:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1711

StackOverflow question that has a workaround:
[React.render replace container instead of inserting into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686796/react-render-replace-container-instead-of-inserting-into)
Workaround involves creating a temporary div, and then replacing the node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some case to da that. I prefer do this:

```
render(){
return [<div>test</div>, <div>test2</div>]
}
```

this is answer on your question: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127