# How to replace DOM elements with a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I inject raw html into my page. I would like to extract all the `<a>` elements in this and replace them with my `<custom-link-component>`. Is there a way of doing this with Vue?

I get raw html from the data service and inject it into a vue component using v-html.

So far I have a mixin that finds all `<a>` elements but can't work out how to replace them:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace `<a>` tags with custom tags, instead of using them directly?

Comment: @WaldemarIce I get raw html as data from a content management system I have no control over - I inject it to a vue component using v-html directive

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to achieve what you want in this way. If you want to use vue component instead of links, you have to place them in your markup as components like [vue router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) as an example:

```
  <!-- literal string -->
  <router-link to="home">Home</router-link>
  <!-- renders to -->
  <a href="home">Home</a>
```

It was discussed [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/replace-html-elements-with-vue-components?page=1), look like same question.

Comment: I get raw html from the content management system and inject it with v-html directive - so i have no compositional control over the incoming html

Comment: In this case you could try another framework, not vue? I'm pretty sure, that it's possible to do this using dojo. React also may have a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535973/is-it-possible-to-replace-dom-elements-with-react take a look.