# Using ReactDOM.render without "container"

Tags: reactjs, render

I need to use React render:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        { ReactDOM.render(str) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But it is not allowed to use like that without container assignment.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686796/react-render-replace-container-instead-of-inserting-into/58385910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`ReactDOMServer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) and in particular the [`.renderToString`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) and [`.renderToStaticMarkup`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) methods.

something like

```
import {renderToStaticMarkup} from 'react-dom/server';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        { rendertostaticmarkup(str) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the above will escape the rendered html and you will actually see the code. If you want to use the rendered html as *live* html you will need to use the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) property.

```
import {renderToStaticMarkup} from 'react-dom/server';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:renderToStaticMarkup(str)}}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`ReactDOM.render` is a function that takes two arguments the what to render and where to render it...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const str = 'Hello There.'

ReactDOM.render(str, document.getElementById('root'));
```

First arg is the `str` and the second where to render `document.getElementById('root')`

More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html