# ReactDOM.hydrate replace container instead of inserting into

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, hydration

First of all, [there is a similar question to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686796/react-render-replace-container-instead-of-inserting-into). I intentionally chose a similar title but this question is slightly different.

I have some server side rendered React code. It gives me HTML something like this:

```
<main>
  <article>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>dolor sit amet</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>dolor sit amet</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>dolor sit amet</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

I am currently implementing partial hydration, ie. instead of having one big React app on my page that mounts at some root element, I am only hydrating parts of the page with their corresponding components.

That means I have an `<Article>` component like this

```
function Article() => (
  <article>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>dolor sit amet</p>
  </article>
)
```

That I am mounting at the first article, ie.

```
const container = document.querySelector('main > article:first-child');
ReactDOM.hydrate(<Article />, container);
```

I was hoping that would hydrate the first `<article>` element and leave the rest alone, which works, except of using and hydrating the `<article>` element `ReactDOM` actually mounts inside the `<Article />` inside the DOM element resulting in this HTML:

```
<main>

  <article>
    <article>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>dolor sit amet</p>
    </article>
  </article>

  ^ -- <article> inside <article>, not cool

  <article>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>dolor sit amet</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>dolor sit amet</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Now I am wondering if there is any way I can make `ReactDOM` *use* that container instead of inserting into it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Uhm, well I ended up writing a pull request for preact to do just this and it actually got merged: https://github.com/preactjs/preact/pull/1557